# How can I load a deck of cards based on these instructions? C

Tags: c

**These are the instructions my professor gave me for a Lab in C**

**--SOLVED--**

```
struct singlecard
{
  int cardnum;
  char face;
  char suit;
};
```

Your program must have the functions named as follows:

Main() - Calls "LoadDeck()" and "DealCards()."

LoadDeck() will fill just the "cardnum" of the array with a unique number between 1 and 52.  It will do this by selecting a random number and then calling the function "CheckDup()" to see if the number is a duplicate.  It will then call "LoadFace()" and "LoadSuit()."

CheckDup() will receive the trial number and the deck of cards as input, and will return back a Boolean.

LoadFace() will go through the deck and put the appropriate value in "face" of the array by using just the "cardnum" the modulus operator to extract the value from the string "A23456789TJQK."

LoadSuit() will go through the deck and put the appropriate suit value in "suit" by using a method similar to "LoadFace()" where the suit string is "HDCS."

DealCards() will display the cards.

**My question is, how can I check that there are no duplicate faces in each suit without a ton of if statements? Please disregard the fact that I'm not sending the "cardnum" as a parameter to the functions LoadFace and LoadSuit, Also I'm using srand(1) for debugging purposes. So far the output has unique card number and the correct amount of faces and suits (13, 4), but I'm not sure how I can insert a nonduplicate element from here.Any advice would be helpful. Also, a simple assign and shuffle of an array isn't allowed :( **

**EDIT checkDup and LoadDeck currently load the deck with a unique card number but not a unique card face and suit. It just counts the number of A faces 2 faces 3 faces King faces etc. It also makes sure that there are 13 cards in each suit. I want to insert unique faces and suits into the stuct array so that I don't have say two 7 of spades.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


struct singlecard {
    int cardnum;
    char face;
    char suit;
};


int i, deckSize = 52;
char suits[] = {"HDCS"};
char faces[] = {"A23456789TJQK"};


void DealCards(struct singlecard Deck[]) {

    //SortCards();
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < deckSize; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
            printf("[%d %c-%c]  %d\n", Deck[i].cardnum, Deck[i].face, Deck[i].suit, i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("[%d %c-%c] ", Deck[i].cardnum, Deck[i].face, Deck[i].suit);
        }
    }

}

int CheckDupe(struct singlecard Deck[],int n) {

    int check = 0, j;
    for (j = 0; j < deckSize; j++) {
        if (n == Deck[j].cardnum || n == 0) {
           return check = 1;
        }

    }
    return check;

}

void LoadSuit(struct singlecard Deck[],int n) 
{  
        Deck[i].suit = suits[(n-1) % 4];
}

void LoadFace(struct singlecard Deck[],int n) {

        Deck[i].face = faces[(n-1) % 13];

} 
void LoadDeck(struct singlecard Deck[]){

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < deckSize;) {
        int random_number = rand() % 53;
        if (CheckDupe(Deck,random_number) == 0) {

            Deck[i].cardnum = random_number;
            LoadFace(Deck,Deck[i].cardnum);
            LoadSuit(Deck,Deck[i].cardnum);
            i++;
        }
    }   
}

int main(){
    struct singlecard Deck[52];
    LoadDeck(Deck);
    DealCards(Deck);
    return 0;
}
```

**Current Output**

```
[5 5-H] [36 T-S] [6 6-D] [29 3-H]  4
[12 Q-S] [19 6-C] [25 Q-H] [13 K-H]  8
[42 3-D] [38 Q-D] [14 A-D] [22 9-D]  12
[16 3-S] [40 A-S] [51 Q-C] [35 9-C]  16
[24 J-S] [4 4-S] [20 7-S] [43 4-C]  20
[31 5-C] [9 9-H] [11 J-C] [48 9-S]  24
[49 T-H] [18 5-D] [41 2-H] [21 8-H]  28
[50 J-D] [52 K-S] [3 3-C] [27 A-C]  32
[39 K-C] [8 8-S] [33 7-H] [23 T-C]  36
[44 5-S] [17 4-H] [32 6-S] [45 6-H]  40
[30 4-D] [28 2-S] [2 2-D] [7 7-C]  44
[26 K-D] [34 8-D] [15 2-C] [47 8-C]  48
[10 T-D] [37 J-H] [1 A-H] [46 7-D]  52
```

Comment: we don't care about your whole homework. It would be better to reduce the amount of code and text of your question and focus on the real problem, creating a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, this is pretty much my first time uploading here. I got desperate.

Comment: Are you saying that the objective of all of this is to generate a _shuffled_ deck from the various card attributes?

Comment: basically yes. With random numbers. He doesn't want an array simply assigned appropriate values and then shuffled which would make it a lot easier and not have to check for dupes as there's a fixed amount of faces and cards.

Comment: So use a comparison function for the `singlecard` structure.

Comment: Your `LoadFace` and `LoadSuit` functions don't fit the spec - they're meant to be using the value in `cardnum` to work out what face/suit the card is not randomly picking it

Comment: Just an hint, but when it is stated that *"LoadFace() will go through the deck and put the appropriate value in "face" of the array by using just the "cardnum" the modulus operator to extract the value from the string "A23456789TJQK."*, you should actually use the modulus operator to convert cardnum to a face (it's a one liner...). You should have already shuffled the deck in loaddeck().

Comment: Wouldn't that still involve a bunch of if statements? I feel like I'm already using to many.

Comment: I know I'm not using cardnum as a param at the moment. I'm just stuck on this comparison logic.

Comment: @TylerJTucker: Per your last edit, if you have to add each card attribute to the cards in the array separately, then yes, you're going to need a TON of conditional statements.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Why? After having shuffled the deck of cards (their cardnum) you only need a modulus and an integer division to find the face and the suit given the card number.

Comment: That's what I'm worried about. It seems like the lab is not intended to have a TON of conditional statements. Is there an easy way of assigning a suit after a random number is chosen in the LoadFace function? Or am I still looking at loads of conditional statements?

Comment: OT: Your `CheckDupe` can be simplified a lot. Just `return` the first time you have `check = 1;` Then you'll get rid of a lot of (confusing) lines.

Comment: OT: Are you being taught to use global variables? It's (nearly) always a bad idea.

Comment: I had more return statements at first but I kept getting a warning for GNU I think, saying that there's a chance of a returning nothing. something about -wreturn. LoadFace and LoadSuit were recursive at first and were giving me trouble so I added return variables. Then I resorted to just returning bool.

Comment: Not being taught to use them, no worries haha. It's just for simplicity.

Comment: You can simplify to: `int CheckDupe(int n) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < deckSize; j++) {
      if (n == Deck[j].cardnum || n == 0) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you are facing is because you've not read and followed your homework instructions properly, notably this bit:

> LoadFace() will go through the deck and put the appropriate value in
>   "face" of the array by using just the "cardnum" the modulus operator
>   to extract the value from the string "A23456789TJQK."

Imagine you've listed out each card in order like so with the card number.

```
 1. Ace of Hearts
 2. Two of Hearts
 ....
 14. Ace of Diamonds
 15. Two of Diamonds
```

Do you notice a pattern? Every 13th card has the same face. The modulus operator (aka `%`) can be used to find out which of those 13 faces a specific value of `cardnum` relates to like this. `cardnum % 13` will always be between 0 and 12. Because your first card starts at 1, you need to subtract 1 first before doing getting modulus. Your `LoadFace` function then becomes this.

```
void LoadFace() {
    for (i = 0; i < deckSize;) {
        Deck[i].face = faces[(Deck[i].cardnum-1) % 13];
    }
}
```

If you want to know if two cards have the same face based on their `cardnum` you can just compare `Deck[a].cardnum % 13` and `Deck[b].cardnum % 13`.

So long as you don't put the same `cardnum` in twice, you know your deck will always contain unique cards.

Comment: After checking the comments it seems like the only way to accomplish this with said instructions is to use the modulus operator and the cardnum. Thanks, Chris, I'll look into it.

Comment: Won't this make it so the suits are in order? For example, based on my output. Won't the next 13 cards always be the same suit?                                                                                            [6 3-H] [36 5-H] [32 6-H] [50 8-H]  4
[42 3-H] [4 J-H] [18 3-H] [40 5-H]  8

Comment: No because to get the suit, you divide the cardnum by 4 (after subtracting 1 from it)

Comment: well... This is why I'm still in college lol Thanks, Chris. I got it working. I can't upvote your answer tho. I'm too much of a pleb.

Answer (score 0):

> `CheckDup` will receive the trial number and the deck of cards as input, and will return back a Boolean.

which would translate to the following declaration

```
bool CheckDup( const int trial, const struct singlecard deck[], const unsigned int deckSize );
```

And should check the `deck` if the `trial` card do not exists yet ( probably `true` if a duplicate is found ), probably by iterating through the `deck`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your question.

*you want to find out, using `checkDup()` if that card has already been dealt*

you could maintain an array (or list whatever) of the card numbers that have been dealt. Then simply search through that array every time `checkDup` is called.

Comment: Currently checkDup already checks if a card has been dealt. I want to figure out a way to insert nonduplicate faces into the single card struct, with matching suits. (as only A,2,3..K to a suit). In my output, the face 7 spade is on card 30 and 26 at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry didnt get what you want. Please.. if you could explain it again

Comment: checkDup and LoadDeck currently load the deck with a unique card number but not a unique card face and suit. It just counts the number of A faces 2 faces 3 faces King faces etc. It also makes sure that there are 13 cards in each suit. I want to insert unique faces and suits into the stuct array so that I don't have say two 7 of spades.

Comment: I thought you had a unique card number for each card in the deck. If that is the case, you simply have a one to one correspondence between cardnum  and face and suit. you can simply take modulus like such `deck[i].face=faces[deck[i].cardnum%13]`(as described in the comments on the question).

Comment: I do have a unique card number. I'll look into taking the modulus of the card number.